# Sourcetree pushing with the wrong user?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

**Background:**

- I have two GitHub accounts: a main account and a rarely-used account.
- If I remember correctly, I have used both of them with the copy of Sourcetree on my laptop.
- I currently have just my main GitHub account listed in my Sourcetree's `Tools-->Options-->Authentication` settings page.

**Problem:**

- When I try to push a branch from my laptop to my GitHub remote for my main account, it fails, with the git error message indicating that I had actually tried to push with my rarely-used account, even though it's nowhere to be found in my Sourcetree settings pages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Atlassian team provided a solution for this ([here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Multiple-git-accounts-on-SourceTree/qaq-p/722733)):

- Open the repo
- Click "Settings"
- Double click on the "origin" item in the listing
- Edit the url to add your username before the URL of the repo. Here are some examples:
  https://USERNAME@contoso.com/repo/blah.git
  https://USERNAME@github.com/host/repo_name
- You should be prompted for a password the next time you try to push or pull

Comment: Only solution working on MAC, you saved my day

Comment: this worked for me too. it really shouldn't be this hard :-(

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve the problem by opening up my Sourcetree `userhosts` file, located at (on Windows 10): `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\userhosts`, as hinted at in [Atlassian's documentation for how to reset your Sourctree settings](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/how-to-wipe-sourcetree-preferences-412484640.html).

The file only contained these lines:

```
github.com
<my-rarely-used-account>@gmail.com
```

I deleted that second line which referenced my rarely-used account, restarted Sourcetree, tried to push again, and this time it prompted me for my GitHub password, and I could see that the username was (correctly) my main GitHub username. I entered my password and the push succeeded.

Comment: This solves the problem at first (+1 for that), but if you need the second account for another push you have to edit the file again.